# Why are there 2 unencrypted rdsadmin connections to my RDS instance?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, postgresql-14

When I look at unencrypted connections to my RDS instance, I see 2 from the `rdsadmin` user. These are not coming from my application, and must be managed by AWS. Is there any documentation about these, or how to force them to use encryption?

```
select * from pg_stat_ssl join pg_stat_activity on pg_stat_ssl.pid = pg_stat_activity.pid where ssl = 'f';


-[ RECORD 1 ]----+---------------------------------
pid              | 15497
ssl              | f
version          | 
cipher           | 
bits             | 
client_dn        | 
client_serial    | 
issuer_dn        | 
datid            | 16384
datname          | rdsadmin
pid              | 15497
leader_pid       | 
usesysid         | 10
usename          | rdsadmin
application_name | PostgreSQL JDBC Driver
client_addr      | 
client_hostname  | 
client_port      | -1
backend_start    | 2023-08-10 10:49:38.897878+00
xact_start       | 
query_start      | 2023-08-24 00:04:46.134798+00
state_change     | 2023-08-24 00:04:46.134818+00
wait_event_type  | Client
wait_event       | ClientRead
state            | idle
backend_xid      | 
backend_xmin     | 
query_id         | 
query            | SELECT value FROM rds_heartbeat2
backend_type     | client backend
-[ RECORD 2 ]----+---------------------------------
pid              | 6860
ssl              | f
version          | 
cipher           | 
bits             | 
client_dn        | 
client_serial    | 
issuer_dn        | 
datid            | 16384
datname          | rdsadmin
pid              | 6860
leader_pid       | 
usesysid         | 10
usename          | rdsadmin
application_name | 
client_addr      | 
client_hostname  | 
client_port      | -1
backend_start    | 2023-08-12 20:39:03.838202+00
xact_start       | 
query_start      | 2023-08-24 00:04:52.645568+00
state_change     | 2023-08-24 00:04:52.645632+00
wait_event_type  | Client
wait_event       | ClientRead
state            | idle
backend_xid      | 
backend_xmin     | 
query_id         | 3694949039461716331
query            | COMMIT
backend_type     | client backend
```

Answer (score 2):

The client_port of -1 means these are local connections, through the Unix-domain socket.  Those don't support SSL, nor do they need it. Since the data doesn't traverse a network, it is not susceptible to eavesdropping/MITM.  Anyone who can get their hands on the data in transit is already in a position to do whatever they want.